# about generalization of bézout's theorem

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I started to study algebraic geometry by the hartshorne's book. In Theorem 7.7 he claims that if Y is variety in $\mathbf{P}^n$ and H is a hypersurface not containing Y, and $Z_1,...,Z_s$ are the irreducible components of $Y\cap H$ then $\sum_{j=1}^{s}i(Y,H;Z_j) = (degY)(degH)$. Where
$i(Y,H;Z_j)$ is the intersection multiplicity of $Y$ and $H$ along $Z_j$, and $degY$ is the dregree of $Y$ wich is (the dimension of Y)! times the leading coeficient of the Hilbert polynomial of Y, and same, mutatis mutandis for $degH$.

I understand the demonstration of this theorem, but I'm searchig for some explicit example where I can in fact exhibit a variety and a hipersurface, calculate their degrees, and their irreducible components. Someone have any suggestion, or a suggestion of a book where I can find this?(In the  book's exercises, he asks to claculate the dimension of Segre and Veronese's embbeding, but I'm searching for more "concrete" )

Thank you for your time.

Comment: did you try Joe Harris' "Algebraic Geometry"?

Comment: Not yet, I will search for this, thank you!